# Pass python variable to html file. Jinja not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I know that we can use Python variables in .html file but in this case, I don't know how to do that.

In routes.py, I have an integer "inside_limit" and I passed it to my .html file. But the html file does not realize the value I passed in. How can I fix that?

I googled that and I got the answer that if we want to put variables into string, we must use 'f' format but now it doesn't work

My code's here:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="{{ url_for('task', kind=f'daiso11_1_{inside_limit}') }}">
...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post a traceback of the error you're getting? Your issue may be the f-string nested in the template substitution. Is it erroring on the `url_for`, or `inside_limit`?

Comment: You are missing a closing } for your endblock

Comment: I fixed that "}" but it still not working

Comment: When you say `the html file does not realize the value I passed in`, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Does Flask throw an exception, or does it render the HTML incorrectly? Can you post the HTML that is returned by Flask? That may help figure out the cause of the issue.

Comment: In my routes.py I have something like this: ```return render_template(question.html, inside_limit=10)```. Then I want to pass the ```inside_limit``` to the url, because, actually, the ```inside_limit``` is not a static value.